# How to hide these dots in left margin of PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

When an object's function overrides two functions, the left side margin will have two dots(seen the picture). The two dots will flash when I scroll the editor. It's annoying, I want to disable the two dots. So, how to ?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can't disable the gutter icons. The problems you are having sound like they might be related to this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19680 (not fixed yet)

Comment: You cannot disable those gutter icons

Answer (score 2):

File -> Settings... -> Editor -> General -> Gutter Icons, then uncheck "Show gutter icons"

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible to hide this information. Also with distraction or presentation View this information hold in gutter left.
[ref doc PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigating-through-the-hierarchy-of-methods.html)

There is a bugfix or evolution open for that : [bugfix open](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6580#)